# IF / ELSEIF statement inside $output

Tags: php

Can someone explain me how to add if / elseif statemnts inside the $output?

Thank you!

Here's the code:

```
        $output .= "  
                 <tr>  
                     <td class='signal-list'><a href data-toggle='modal' data-target='#showSignal$id'>$id</a></td>
                      <td class='signal-list'>$date_added</td>
                      <td class='signal-list'>$pr</td>
                      <td>$ac</td>
                      <td class='signal-list'>$entr</td>
                      <td>$dir</td>
                      <td>$clo</td>
                      <td>$p_l</td>
                 </tr>  
            ";  
       }  
       $output .= '</table>';  
  }  
  echo $output;
```

I want to add this code down below inside the $output

```
  if($status == 'Profit') {

  echo "<td class='signal-list'><p class='label label-success'>PROFIT</p></td>";

    } elseif($status == 'Loss') {

  echo "<td class='signal-list'><p class='label label-danger'>&nbsp; LOSS &nbsp;</p></td>";

    } else {

 echo "<td class='signal-list'><p class='label label-primary'>&nbsp; LIVE &nbsp;</p></td>";

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $output .= "  
             <tr>  
                 <td class='signal-list'><a href data-toggle='modal' data-target='#showSignal$id'>$id</a></td>
                  <td class='signal-list'>$date_added</td>
                  <td class='signal-list'>$pr</td>
                  <td>$ac</td>
                  <td class='signal-list'>$entr</td>
                  <td>$dir</td>
                  <td>$clo</td>
                  <td>$p_l</td>
                  ";
if($status == 'Profit') {
    $output .= "<td class='signal-list'><p class='label label-success'>PROFIT</p></td>";
}
elseif($status == 'Loss') {
    $output .= "<td class='signal-list'><p class='label label-danger'>&nbsp; LOSS &nbsp;</p></td>";
} else {
    $output .= "<td class='signal-list'><p class='label label-primary'>&nbsp; LIVE &nbsp;</p></td>";
}                 
$output .= "
             </tr>  
        ";

$output .= '</table>';  
echo $output;
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough.. I want to add this code inside current $output not new one and inside HTML table..

Comment: Sorry, using .= you use the same string, is not a new one
is the same as $output = $output . " something"

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you want the additional cells to come before or after the existing cells, but all you need to do is take the `<tr>` outside of the `$output` addition, and then change your `echo` to append to the `$output` variable with `.=`.

Here's an example showcasing the additions coming afterwards, but you can easily just swap the `Existing cells` and `New cells` around if you want them to come beforehand; the structure will still be correct.

```
<?php

// Start the table and table row - note that you do not use `.=` here
$output = '<table><tr>';

// Existing cells
$output .= "  
    <td class='signal-list'><a href data-toggle='modal' data-target='#showSignal$id'>$id</a></td>
    <td class='signal-list'>$date_added</td>
    <td class='signal-list'>$pr</td>
    <td>$ac</td>
    <td class='signal-list'>$entr</td>
    <td>$dir</td>
    <td>$clo</td>
    <td>$p_l</td>
    ";

// New cells
if($status == 'Profit') {
  $output .= "<td class='signal-list'><p class='label label-success'>PROFIT</p></td>";
} elseif($status == 'Loss') {
  $output .= "<td class='signal-list'><p class='label label-danger'>&nbsp; LOSS &nbsp;</p></td>";
} else {
  $output .= "<td class='signal-list'><p class='label label-primary'>&nbsp; LIVE &nbsp;</p></td>";
}

// End the table row and table itself
$output .= '</tr></table>';  

echo $output;
```

Hope this helps! :)